# Make all div children have the same height

Tags: html, css

My website has 3 boxes but also, a very definitive margin between all 3. As such, I don't *think* I can use CSS `display:table` to fix this issue so [How to make div boxes with floats have the same height with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990669/how-to-make-div-boxes-with-floats-have-the-same-height-with-dynamic-content) doesn't help :(

```css
.wrapper div {
 float:left;
}    
.box1 {
 background:blue;
 margin-right:10%;
}
.box2 {
 background:red;
 margin:0 10%;
}
.box3 {
 background:green;
 margin-left:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box1">asdf </div>
 <div class="box2">asdf  sadf<br /> saf safs<br /> fsdf  saf</div>
 <div class="box3">
            asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />
            asdf <br />asdf <br />sfsa dfsdaf sdf sdf 
        </div>    
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q96pr8n5/)**

In my head, the wrapper has a height (which is the height of the highest child), and as such I would have hoped adding `height:inherit` would have worked in .box1, .box2 or .box3 but not

`display:flex` features are [not fully supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=order) so I don't want to use it.

How do I make all 3 the same height without using a fixed height.

Comment: Flexbox to the rescue: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use CSS display:table to fix this.  Below are the CSS, HTML and Fiddle

```css
.wrapper {display:table;}

.box1 {background:pink;display: table-cell;}

.box2 {background:red;display: table-cell;}

.box3 {background:green;display: table-cell;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box1">asdf </div>
        <div class="box2">asdf  sadf<br /> saf safs<br /> fsdf  saf</div>
        <div class="box3">
        asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />sfsa dfsdaf sdf sdf
        </div>    
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohrab12/dn6uckoa/)

Comment: How does this witch craft work. You have styled `.table-row` yet I see no HTML element reference this class. Also, this has lost my very specific margins

Comment: The .table-row didn't need to be int there.  I removed it from the CSS.  In regards to the margins, you would either have to give padding to the current cells, or add blank DIVs with specific widths to serve as spacing.  @MyDaftQuestions

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use a jQuery library, use this -
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Then its as simple as assigning a class and then do this:

```
$(".equal-heights").matchHeight();
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it won't work after you change the content unless you call `matchHeight` again

Comment: Good point. You could just add this in whichever function that causes the content to change, but yes - its not as seamless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) by zurb foundation.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" data-equalizer>
    <div class="box1" data-equalizer-watch>asdf </div>
    <div class="box2" data-equalizer-watch>asdf  sadf<br /> saf safs<br /> fsdf  saf</div>
    <div class="box3" data-equalizer-watch>asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />asdf <br />sfsa dfsdaf sdf sdf </div>    
</div>
```

Add .js:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
```

Start equalizer:

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

---

---

---

I know you don't want to use flex but just in case.

You can try something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdua4fw3/):

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
    background:blue;
    margin-right:10%;
}

.box2 {
    background:red;
    margin:0 10%;
}

.box3 {
    background:green;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```